# can ranges split be used with a predicate?

Tags: c++, split, c++20, std-ranges

Can this double loop be rewritten using ranges views split() ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <span>

struct MyPair
{
    int a;
    char b;
};


vector<MyPair> path = {{1,'a'},{1,'z'},{2,'b'},{2,'y'}};
vector<span<MyPair> > spans;

for (int i=0; i < path.size();)
{
    auto r = path | ranges::views::drop(i) | views::take_while([&](const MyPair& p){return p.a == path[i].a;});
    int size = ranges::distance(r);
    span<Range> ranges(&path[i], size);
    spans.push_back(ranges);
    i += size ;
}
```

I want a view of views looking like

```
{{{1,'a'},{1,'z'}},{{2,'b'},{2,'y'}}}
```

Comment: It seems like you want the proposed [`views::chunk_by`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2443r1.html).

Comment: @cpplearner Not only proposed but also C++23 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can this double loop be rewritten using ranges views split() ?

Since you're not using a range as a delimiter to split the original range, instead you're using a predicate to split the range,  `views::split` doesn't actually solve the problem.

However, C++23 adopted [`views::chunk_by`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2443r1.html), and according to its description in [range.chunk.by.overview]:

> `chunk_by_view` takes a `view` and a predicate, and splits the view into
> `subrange`s between each pair of adjacent elements for which the
> predicate returns `false`.

The for-loop can be rewritten using `views::chunk_by` with the appropriate predicate:

```
vector<MyPair> path = ...
auto spans = path | std::views::chunk_by([](const auto& l, const auto& r) {
                                           return l.a == r.a; 
                                         });
```

But currently, no compiler implements this range adaptor, the alternative is to use range-v3's [`views::group_by`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1views_1_1group__by__fn.html).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G6j8TxTfY)

It is worth noting that `ranges::views::group_by` is *not* functionally equivalent to `std::views::chunk_by`: the former always compares the *first* element in each subrange with each subsequent one, while the latter always compare *consecutive* elements.

Comment: this is science fiction but excellent

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of views::chunk_by, here is my code, using a good old for loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <span>

struct MyPair
{
    int a;
    char b;
};

vector<MyPair> path = {{1,'a'},{1,'z'},{2,'b'},{2,'y'}};

vector<span<MyPair> > spans;

int i_prev=0;
for (int i=0;i < path.size(); i++)
{
    if (path[i].a != path[i_prev].a)
    {
        spans.push_back(span<MyPair>(&path[i_prev], i - i_prev));
                i_prev=i ;
    }
}
spans.push_back(span<MyPair>(&path[i_prev], path.size() - i_prev));
```

Comment: chunk_by is way better